# Recursive mistake

Tags: javascript, recursion

When my code above reach at the end of optgroup, it's stop... dont read the last option element... what is going on ? thanks

console.log('entering');

- this is the html 
            select ---
              option
              optgroup ---
                 option
                 option
              option

  ```
  var t,v = '';

  el = $(selector).get(0);

  if(el.hasChildNodes()){

          var li = '<ul>' ;
          for(var i = 0; i <  el.childNodes.length; i++){
                  console.log('-----'+i+' '+el.childNodes[i].nodeName);
                  //console.log(el.childNodes[i].nodeName + ' -> '+ $(el.childNodes[i]).text());
                  if(el.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'OPTION'){

                      t = $(el.childNodes[i]).text();
                      v = $(el.childNodes[i]).val();

                       li = li + "<li value='"+v+"' >"+t+"</li>";

                  }else if(el.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'OPTGROUP'){

                      if(el.childNodes[i].hasChildNodes()){
                          var c = MacOsxSelectOptionToLi(el.childNodes[i]);
                          /*var c = '<ul>';
                          for(var j = 0; j <  el.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++){
                                  if(el.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == 'OPTION'){
                                       t = $(el.childNodes[i].childNodes[j]).text();
                                       v = $(el.childNodes[i].childNodes[j]).val();
                                       c = c + "<li value='"+v+"' >"+t+"</li>";
                                  }                                   
                          }
                          c = c+ '</ul>';
                          */
                      }else{
                          var c = '';
                      }
                      var t = $(el.childNodes[i]).attr('label');                          
                      li = li + "<li class='optiongroup' >"+t+c+"</li>";

                  }



          }

          return li + '</ul>';
  }
  ```

Comment: It would be helpful if the HTML & script is put up in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

See, if you have declared the entire code in the function `MacOsxSelectOptionToLi()` and using the selector to get the html select element, the code goes infinite recursion. Hence, make the call from some other function. E.g.

```
function initFunction() {
    var convertSelectToULCode = MacOsxSelectOptionToLi($(selector));
}
```